# Can not load image on iOS Release mode

Tags: ios, react-native, metro-bundler

I faced this issue only on release mode for iOS, it works as well for iOS debug mode and Android (both bebug and release mode)

All local images cannot be loaded

> Task <92985F45-14B8-42E9-881D-7E2553768A91>.<1> finished with error
> [-1100] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1100 "The requested URL
> was not found on this server." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=The
> requested URL was not found on this server.,
> NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/18F697ED-7734-48AC-90B6-7878AA93B4BC/Library/Application%20Support/.expo-internal/assets/res/my_app/Assets/Icons/new_logo.webp,
> NSErrorFailingURLKey=file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/18F697ED-7734-48AC-90B6-7878AA93B4BC/Library/Application%20Support/.expo-internal/assets/res/my_app/Assets/Icons/new_logo.webp,
> _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
> "LocalDataTask <92985F45-14B8-42E9-881D-7E2553768A91>.<1>" ), _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <92985F45-14B8-42E9-881D-7E2553768A91>.<1>,
> NSUnderlyingError=0x280cb4810 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork
> Code=-1100 "(null)"}}

my metro config

```
module.exports = {
    transformer: {
        assetPlugins: ['expo-asset/tools/hashAssetFiles'],
        getTransformOptions: async () => ({
            transform: {
                experimentalImportSupport: false,
                inlineRequires: false
            }
        })
    }
};
```

Does anyone have a suggestion for my issue? Any response would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

WebP images are not supported by iOS do try jpg, png or any other formats

Comment: I don't think so, because the debug mode work as well

Comment: @GianhTran Are you using some specific library for the same?